# java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found Android Nougat

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, android-7.0-nougat

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found - Android Nougat
```

I dont understand this problem if this is from the server misconfiguration or I should set up something specific in the app, This is my first time encountering this problem actually.

So I tried openssl command to check and returned:

```
Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
```

So in my `app` to make it work I just returned `true` if the certificate is untrusted other than that `false`.

And I checked `network_security_config` in android samples but still it shows same certification error.

Unfortunately I cannot show the url, all I can say is that its using

```
issuer=/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
```

and I also checked this from `system` certificates in my phone I didnt see this.

What I need is that it should not work even if I dont set return `true` if it is `untrusted`, Can I do that?

Is there something that I missed? Some configurations in android app?

Comment: [Symantec is no longer honored as a root certificate authority by Chrome](https://security.googleblog.com/2017/09/chromes-plan-to-distrust-symantec.html), and it would not surprise me if they are doing so for all of Android, given that [they previously revoked one of Symantec's root certificates for Android](http://www.zdnet.com/article/google-strips-chrome-android-trust-for-symantec-root-certificate/).

Comment: @CommonsWare ah yes I read that too, But i thought it was not the case thank you for verifying. Anyway is it ok if I just add a .cert file into my network config? I just made it work but is there any side effects or security concerns?

Comment: @CommonsWare Does network config works on lollipop and up or only for android nougat?

Comment: "I just made it work but is there any side effects or security concerns?" -- well, there are security reasons why Google revoked Symantec's root certificates. Your server team should be switching to a different certificate authority. I am not certain how you have set up network security configuration, but if you are now pinning to that certificate, bear in mind that your app will break if you switch certificates on the server.

Comment: "Does network config works on lollipop and up or only for android nougat?" -- the native network security configuration is only for Android 7.0+. I [backported it to Android 4.2](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-netsecurity), though only if you can manually route your HTTPS requests through my library (e.g., via OkHttp). The native implementation works for all Java-based requests, plus `WebView`-based requests on Android 8.0+.